# ImageSharp MyGet feed does not exist?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, imagesharp

I have forked a repository and it contains an imagesharp dependency. The URL for this is https://www.myget.org/F/imagesharp/api/v3/index.json

I can see there is imagesharp by sixlabors  https://www.myget.org/F/sixlabors/api/v3/index.json but this uses a different namespace so I'm fairly certain it's a different library. does anyone know where the nightly version has gone?

I am trying to update packages through NuGet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you look at the readme on the [ImageSharp repository](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) and follow the links to our myget release then you will see that https://www.myget.org/gallery/sixlabors is the official pre-release source of ImageSharp the namespace was added well over a year ago when the core team formed the Six Labors organsisation around the library and related tools. This was when the old feed stopped being updated and we migrated over to new one.

If you where using the version to ImageSharp from that feed you are massively out of date and will find the API has drastically evolved since then.